# JasperServer: how to change "Jaspersoft: Login" page name to our "Organization: Login" page

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to change "Jaspersoft: Login" page name to our "Organization: Login" page, when we login on `JasperServer` default page name is Jaspersoft: Login? You can see in browser after login.

Comment: You can customize `WEB-INF\jsp\modules\login\login.jsp`

Comment: Can you tell me the exact location where i have to change "Jaspersoft: Login" to "Organization: Login" because i have tried to customize login.jsp but couldn't find how to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find in `WEB-INF\jsp\decoratos\decorators.jsp`
Here you will find Japsersoft default message you can edit that tile or you can edit in `pro_nav_messages.properties` found in bundles and print their and reflect this in your `decorator.jsp`

E.g.

```
<!--default>
<title>Jaspersoft: <decorator:title /></title>
<!--customized message where we edited pro_nav_messages.properties with NAV_020_FULL_TITLE code >
<title><spring:message code='NAV_020_FULL_TITLE'/></title>
```

Comment: but directory of decorator.jsp is different in my case you can find it here- WEB-INF\decorator\decorator.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Changing the company name in the below file worked for me.

/opt/jasper-report-server/apache-tomcatwebapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/bundles/jasperserver_messages.properties